# How would I register a dynamically named variable in an Ansible task?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to retrieve the group ID of two groups (`syslog` and `utmp`) by name using an Ansible task. For testing purposes I have created a playbook to retrieve the information from the Ansible host itself.

```
---
- name: My playbook
  hosts: enabled
  sudo: True
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Determine GIDs
      shell: "getent group {{ item }} | cut -d : -f 3"
      register: gid_{{item}}
      failed_when: gid_{{item}}.rc != 0
      changed_when: false
      with_items:
        - syslog
        - utmp
```

Unfortunately I get the following error when running the playbook:

```
fatal: [hostname] => error while evaluating conditional: gid_syslog.rc != 0
```

How can I consolidate a task like this one into a parametrized form while registering *separate* variables, one *per item*, for later use? So the **goal** is to have variables based on the group name which can then be used in later tasks.

I'm using the `int` filter on `gid_syslog.stdout` and `gid_utmp.stdout` to do some calculation based on the GID in later tasks.

---

I also tried using `gid.{{item}}` and `gid[item]` instead of `gid_{{item}}` to no avail.

---

The following works fine in contrast to the above:

```
---
- name: My playbook
  hosts: enabled
  sudo: True
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - name: Determine syslog GID
      shell: "getent group syslog | cut -d : -f 3"
      register: gid_syslog
      failed_when: gid_syslog.rc != 0
      changed_when: false
    - name: Determine utmp GID
      shell: "getent group utmp | cut -d : -f 3"
      register: gid_utmp
      failed_when: gid_utmp.rc != 0
      changed_when: false
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose there's no easy way for that.  And `register` with `with_items` loop just puts all results of them into an array `variable.results`.  Try the following tasks:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Determine GIDs
      shell: "getent group {{ item }} | cut -d : -f 3"
      register: gids
      changed_when: false
      with_items:
        - syslog
        - utmp
    - debug:
        var: gids
    - assert:
        that:
          - item.rc == 0
      with_items: gids.results
    - set_fact:
        gid_syslog: "{{gids.results[0]}}"
        gid_utmp: "{{gids.results[1]}}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{gid_syslog.stdout}} {{gid_utmp.stdout}}"
```

You can, however, use variable expansion in `set_fact` keys like this:

```
    - set_fact:
        "gid_{{item.item}}": "{{item}}"
      with_items: gids.results
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out, but it's unlikely I'd put that solution as it is longer and more convoluted than even the one were I duplicate everything (at the bottom of my question). Readability is one of the strengths of Ansible otherwise, so working around that will come back to bite me :)

Comment: Set fact supports variables, as opposed to the previous solution's statement, see answer below

Answer (score 14):

Set fact supports variables, as opposed to the previous solution's statement

```yml
- set_fact:
    "{{ item.name }}": "{{ item.val }}"
  when: item.name not in vars           # this is optional. prevents overwriting vars
  with_items:
    - { name: test, val: myalue }
    - { name: notest, val: novalue }
```

Comment: I would give it +10 if I could! :)

Comment: This right here just made my life so much easier!